# CronJob using timezone

Tags: node.js, cron

I'm using CronJob in my NodeJs application. Everything works fine except I want to trigger CronJob according to specific timezone.

```
    const membershipChangeCronJob = new CronJob({
    cronTime: '0 5 12 * * *',
    onTick: function () {
        console.log('********************************************');
        console.log('**********Membership Change Cron Job*************');
        console.log('********************************************');

        membershipeUpdate();

    },
    start: false
});

membershipChangeCronJob.start();
```

Is there anyway I can use moment timezone with CronJob? or is there any other workaround

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can add a parameter or key of

> timeZone

to add the required timezone

```
const membershipChangeCronJob = new CronJob({
    cronTime: '0 5 12 * * *',
    onTick: function () {
        console.log('********************************************');
        console.log('**********Membership Change Cron Job*************');
        console.log('********************************************');

        membershipeUpdate();

    },
    start: false,
    timeZone: 'Asia/Singapore'
});

membershipChangeCronJob.start();
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) with examples

Comment: Please provide any doc reference as well. It will give an idea of what it is used for